# Swashbuckle: Make non-nullable properties required in array type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, autorest

I'm using autoRest to generate a new client from a swagger schema. I have list of DateTime in a model

```
public class DateRange
{
   public IList<DateTime> Dates{ get; set; }
}
```

This the Json swagger schema it is generated from that property

```
  { ...
    "Dates": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "format": "date-time",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
    ...
    }
```

This is the result I am getting after I run autoRest

```
public class DateRange
{

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Dates")]
     public IList<System.DateTime?> Dates{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get a non nullable dateTime property something like this

```
public IList<System.DateTime> Dates{ get; set; }
```

---

Comment: this smells like a bug in autorest, you should report it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Swagger schema so that your property would look like:

```
dates:
    type: "array"
    items:
        format: "date-time"
        type: "string"
        x-nullable: false
```

Then generated the client using `AutoRest` in the command line:

```bsh
autorest --input-file="swagger.json" --output-folder="output" --csharp
```

Resulting in:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dates")]
public IList<System.DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
```

Comment: If this have resolved your question, please accept my answer.